# Need help understanding Minimize main-thread work

Tags: javascript

i'm doing a pagespeed test for my site and the main error for mobile is:

Minimize main-thread work 8.4 s

Consider reducing the time spent parsing, compiling and executing JS. You may find delivering smaller JS payloads helps with this. Learn how to minimize main-thread work

Script Evaluation: 3,610 ms

Style & Layout: 2,441 ms

Other: 1,333 ms

Parse HTML & CSS: 377 ms

Rendering: 329 ms

Script Parsing & Compilation: 209 ms

Garbage Collection: 107 ms

How do i reduce it? the site: https://modestyhut.com.au/

Comment: This isn't WordPress-related. You might have better luck asking on [Webmasters SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.